# How to get Windows8.Identity.AccessControl to work with Windows 8 RP?

Tags: windows-8, acs

I'm using the [ACS LoginControl Nuget Package](http://watwindows8.codeplex.com/) `Windows8.Identity.AccessControl`, more specifically the `Windows8.CSharp.Identity.AccessControl`, but I can't get it to work on Windows 8 RP.

I have tried several different ACS endpoints and namespaces, but all I get is:

> Can't connect to the service. We can't connect to the service you need
>   right now. Check your network connection or try this again later.

when trying to connect. (Fetching the Identity provider list works).
Trying the companion ACS control for Windows Phone 7 works without any issues, so I'm rather confident that the ACS part is setup properly.

Does anybody has any ideas on how I can trouble shoot this?